# The command 'grunt' doesn't generate the folder: dist

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs

I am trying to setup jenkins with grunt. It is the first time that I try, so I need to know if is the correct way.

Step by Step:

1. On Jenkins I installed NodeJs Plugin;
2. On Global Tool Configuration, in NodeJS's section, I pointed the path of the folder installation of the NodeJS: !(https://ibb.co/0j9XGck)
3. I set up the source code management;
4. On build section, clicked add “Execution Shell” and entered shell commands:

```
 npm install
 npm install grunt-cli -g
 grunt
```

5. The console output shows `"Finished: SUCCESS"`. The folder "node_modules" was created but the folder "dist" was not!

If I run the commands in the console the folder "dist" is created.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be different, I do not have enough elements.
However, I would not use a grunt installed by jenkins. Imagine the version on jenkins is different than the version on developers computer!

Install grunt as a dev dependency

```
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

Then, still in package.json add a script with key 'grunt' and value 'grunt'.

```
"scripts": {
  "grunt": "grunt"
   ...
}
```

commit the file.
Now on jenkins run

```
 npm install
 npm run grunt
```